# How to just temporarily disable apt proxy setting for installing packages

Tags: proxy, dependencies, apt

Apt is able to use proxy to install additional packages along with dependencies.
I'm working on a Python project and I needed some extra package that provides a library.

```
---> sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxy.internal'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxy.internal'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxy.internal'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxy.internal'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.internal'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.internal'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.internal'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxy.internal'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How to temporarily disable proxy (without altering the permanent options/settings)? Preferably, from the command line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The quickest method for temporarily disabling proxy configuration **without altering** the permanent settings is to use the command line option like below:

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::proxy=false install <package>
```

This gives the user the mobility between open/public/home network and corporate environments with proxy.
From manual page:

> ```
>    -o, --option
>        Set a Configuration Option; This will set an arbitrary configuration option. The syntax is -o
>        Foo::Bar=bar.  -o and --option can be used multiple times to set different options.
> ```